# Creating one atlas QGIS plan to show multiple features that control atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas, qgis-atlas

I am creating an atlas plan that has multiple features that are controlling the atlas in one plan.

Instead of it generating 3 plans that look the same is it possible to only generate 1?

On my picture the three pink dots are what the atlas is generating images for however it is creating 3 plans for each when I only need one.

Is there a way of automatically sorting this or will I have to manually delete all extra plans?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PJMp.png]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking. The atlas is going to iterate through each feature in the atlas layer, do you want it to skip two of those points because they are close to each other?

Comment: Yes they can be skipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to skip some features you will need to filter the Atlas. In the Atlas properties where you configure things like zoom scale, etc. there is a filter option there.

So if you only want one of the three features to act as an atlas feature then you would have to filter out the others, so you would write something like:

`"field_name" NOT IN('NS35705008', 'CSO000479')`

If you have many features that need to be filtered then you could add an attribute into the layer called something like "in_atlas" with yes/no values and then use `"in_atlas" = 'yes'` as the filter.

Comment: Thank you. The field name suggestion I couldn't get to work but the attribute table  change did  :-)

Comment: @JamieHooper glad to hear it. If it worked then please mark the answer as accepted